# React Router Prompt, prompt for redirect only for specific urls

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to use prompt to stop the user from accidentally redirecting from a page with unsaved changes, the implementation of which is fairly straight forward;

```
<Prompt when={this.state.changesMadeToDesign}
        message="Are you sure you want to abandon your changes?"
    />
```

This is great, the only problem is as the users change the "design" they are redirected around the studio page. This means after they've made a single change they're prompted on every single redirect ("/studio/manage", "/studio/add" etc...) which is extremely annoying, I only want it to redirect when the user leaves the /studio page altogether.

I've tried only rendering the prompt on a state change in `componentWillUnmount` on the main studio page but it must unmount before it takes effect as it doesn't work, I've also checked all the overload props for Prompt but there doesn't seem to be anything to help me, this must have come up before, it seems like pretty common functionality, is there are way to achieve this, with or without prompt?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too, basically what I did was to store this `shouldBlockNavigation` variable outside the component, i.e. in a store or context, which is boolean that switches on or off based on the need. Your triggers to change that is to switch to true if there are changes made to design, and switch to false if the url is already changed (i.e. `history.listen`'s function).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the overhead for that kind of application, otherwise I could just render it in my main routes and control it with redux, I was hoping for existing functionality

Comment: Alright, fair enough, another solution you could do is wrap your design-editing-component with another component that handles the prompt, when you want to navigate to a different page, just raise a flag that you `shouldBlockNavigation`, and once you accept or move out from that component, switch the flag back to false, that's a turn around the `componentWillUnmount` problem.